# Save method in react repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Hi i would like to ask You what do you think about below, especially please pay attention to save method.
My question is blocking or not blocking?

@Repository
class ImageSizeRepositoryInMemoryImpl implements ImageSizeRepository {

```
private volatile Map<String, ImageSize> imageSizes = HashMap.empty();

@Override
public Mono<Void> save(ImageSize imageSize) {
    this.imageSizes = imageSizes.put(imageSize.getName(), imageSize);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

I invoke this method in ma application service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ImageResizeServiceFacade {

    private final ImageSizeRepository imageSizeRepository;

    public Mono<Void> addPredefinedSize(Mono<ImageSizeDto> predefinedSizeDto) {
        return predefinedSizeDto
                //.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .doOnNext(imageSizeDto -> {
                    imageSizeRepository.save(Mapper.ImageSizeMapper.mapFromDto(imageSizeDto)); })
                .then();
    }


Bu i dont know how to test in spock:

class ImageResizerSpec extends Specification implements SampleSize {

    ImageResizeServiceFacade imageResizeServiceFacade = new ResizerConfiguration().imageResizeServiceFacade()

    def "should add new size"() {
        given: "we have new size to add"
        Mono<ImageSizeDto> newSize = Mono.just(imageSizeDto)

        when: "we add new size"
        Mono<Void> empty = imageResizeServiceFacade.addPredefinedSize(newSize)
        empty.block()

        then: "system has this size"
        imageResizeServiceFacade.listPredefinedSizes().blockFirst().name == imageSizeDto.name
    }
```

As we can see above in my test in when block i have to wait for operation to complete, so I use block method...
}

Comment: Yes it is, as the `put` is synchronous and that has to execute before you can `return Mono.empty()`. Although it may run on separate thread there is blocking code in between.

Comment: Please stop tagging your questions with `rx-java` when they are not related to or contain RxJava code.

Comment: Rx-java is simillar to React. and it is reactive programming, so anyone who know rxjava can answer to my question...

Comment: @M.Deinum But I invoke repository method in doOnNext method sa it not blocking?

Comment: But the implementation is blocking...

Comment: I dont understand...